# What is the right way to maintain a "version for the server" - with only config files changed, in Git?

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, version-control

I sometimes work with Codeigniter, and after I'm done developing on the local site, I need to migrate the files to the server. All the files in the `/config/` folder need to be changed to match the Server settings. It's not right to make an entire commit for these changes, do I simply make Git ignore these files altogether, or is there a way to track these changes and apply them with Git at the right moment?

Comment: You could perhaps write a git after_deploy hook that would do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could keep versioned:

- two "value config files", with the right values for each environment
- a template config file, with value placeholder in it (for instance, `@@PORT_NUMBER@@`)
- a script able to *generate* the actual config file depending on the current environment
- a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) which, on checkout, will trigger the script in order to generate the right config file.

[image: content filter driver]

Note: that supposes your template config file has a recognizable content (the filter doesn't have a name or path of the file). See "[Git equivalent of subversion's `$URL$` keyword expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393)" for more on the limitation of git content filter driver).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Your needs. In my company we use other approach.
We've created several environments (where the asterix is internal project name):

- devel - site runs on domain **.local.com*
- test - site run on domain *test.*.company.com*
- beta - *beta.*.company.com*
- production - every other domain.

Based on the domain name we switch automatically configurations.
Basicly config file looks like:

```
<?php
return array(
  '_env' => array(
    'devel' => array(
      // config for devel
    ),
    'production' => array(
      // config for production
    )
  )
);
?>
```

Some frameworks (AFAIR Zend) set the environment name in Virtual Host config (or .htaccess). You should look at: [zend framework auto switch production staging test .. etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510556/zend-framework-auto-switch-production-staging-test-etc)

Have You looked at CI documentation? There's a [section](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Create two folders in the `config` folder. One is called `development` and the other is `production`. Now copy config.php, database.php etc to each of these folders. Now when you are on production server, CodeIgniter will first check the `production` folder for the files. If it is not there, then it uses the default file in the `config` folder. And if you are on development environment, CodeIgniter will first check the `development` folder.

If you want to keep any config file identical to the production and development environment, keep it in `config` folder.

If you want to set the environment then add the following code in .htaccess file:

```
#This code for Development Environment
SetEnv CI_ENV development
```

and

```
#This code for Production Environment
SetEnv CI_ENV production
```