# Ignore configs with git

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

In my project I have config files that have private information. I committed some example templates to Github, but I have the actual configs in my working copy so I can build from it and I don't want them available to commit.

I tried using .gitignore, but the templates are already tracked. I tried `git rm filename` but that tries to delete the templates. I tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged filename` and `git update-index --skip-worktree filename` but they still show up as "modified" when using `git status` (and under Files to Commit in Github for Windows).

Is there any way to ignore changes that I've already made without removing the templates from Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like what a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) is for:

- the smudge part could replace the template content with the actual value (on checkout)
- the clean part could restore the template (on commit)

[image]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

Comment: Will git recognize the cleaned config is unchanged or will it still be added when I do `git add .`? It makes me nervous to commit those files and trust the filter will clean them.

Comment: Actually, a git status will show them unchanged (before git add and git commit) because the clean filter is able to restore them to their original form: so no worries, add and commit won't include those files.

Comment: I do that for instance for gitolite (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/tree/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/gitolite), where I replace the shebang directive (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/gitolite/shebang_replace) but where I restore the original shebang directive (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/gitolite/shebang_restore): those files never show up as modified.

Comment: I guess I'll need to use Cygwin and sed to do the filtering on Windows?

Comment: @Chip no you can use sed on Windows, without using Cygwin. I use GoW https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki. Plus don't forget those script are executed by git, in a git bash session (even on Windows), so `sed` is there (packaged with msysgit) For example: `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217\bin\sed.exe`.