# Track file but ignore changes, as repo config

Tags: linux, git

It is possible to track one file, but discard changes to it:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

But this is local setting.

How can I make this visible to my team members, without forcing them to locally do the `git update-index --assume-unchanged` dance?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Setup a server hook like `pre-receive`. It rejects a push if the push contains new commits that change the file. Or setup a local hook like `pre-commit` which runs `git reset <file>` to exclude the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring server config files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966898/ignoring-server-config-files-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+config+file+ignore+changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817040/ignore-configs-with-git

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't.  Git doesn't support doing this and using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` for this purpose is not a supported use of that feature.

If you have a config file or other file that needs to change depending on the user or system, then check in a template and generate it as part of a local build step.  For example, GitHub uses templating and [a set of scripts](https://github.com/github/scripts-to-rule-them-all) to set up local configuration in a project-independent way.