# How do not change development team while doing git pull?

Tags: xcode, git, github, gitattributes

There are two developers at the project, each of them has his own Apple developer account and there is no team account. After pulling changes from git, which contains change in .pbxproj file needs to change team back and it's quite annoying. 
[xCode signing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkPau.png)

after team changing there is a high probability this change should push to origin and teammate will need to fix team too

[changes in GitHub Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXKKC.png)

I suspect that it can be fixed with .gitattributes file, but have no idea, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not store per-user data in your repository.  This file should be ignored and not checked into your repository, and if you need to create this file on developer systems, it should be generated from a template, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723835/track-file-but-ignore-changes-as-repo-config/57733633).