# .gitignore for Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, git, swift

I'm always nervous to make pushes of code to a Github repo with authentication tokens and variables. I have had an issue in the past with exposed keys and since I am new to Xcode, I'm curious as to what files I should be adding to `.gitignore`. The main areas where I am most nervous about displaying in my public repo is my Parse and Facebook keys. The Facebook keys are set up within my `.plist` and my Parse keys appear in my `AppDelegate.swift` file. What should my approach be, and going forward, how should I set up environment variables to prevent issues in the future.

Comment: Github do it for you: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the recommended [`Swift.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore) does not ignore those files, then you would need to manage them with a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)).

The idea is to manage those plist or swift files in version, but with *template* placeholders in place of the actual (sensitive) values.

- the smudge part could replace the template content with the actual value (on checkout)
- the clean part could restore the template (on commit)

[image: smudge]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The main idea is: if a data is confidential, it should *not* be in the repo (at all): the smudge script would replace the placeholder values with actual values fetched *outside* of the repo.