# the concepts of git ignore and not commiting, but still using, global variables

Tags: meteor, global-variables, commit, gitignore, api-key

I'm a bit of a newbie, but already running apps with Meteor.js. Since I'm now working with API keys I'm finally realizing that security is a thing, and so I placed my keys in a settings.json, and am instructed not to commit, or to .gitignore the file. But despite reading the documentation, this all seems very counter-intuitive. If I need the variables to make my HTTP requests, then how can my app possibly function without adding my keys, in some form, to the repo? I know the answer is "it can," but how? (in general terms, I don't need a Meteor specialist yet) .

Typing this question out makes me feel pretty ignorant for the stage I'm at, but the docs out there for some reason are not clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can *generate* the file with sensitive information on `git checkout`.

That is called a `smudge` script, part of a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309), using using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

That '`smudge`' script( that you have to write) would need to:

- fetch the right key (from a source *outside* the repo, that way no risk to add and push by mistake)
- generate the  `settings.json`, using a tracked manifest *template*  `settings.json.tpl` with placeholder value in it to replace.

That means:

- the template `settings.json.tpl` is added to the git repo
- the generate file `settings.json` is declared in the `.gitignore` file and never versioned.