# Git Repo Restrict File Name From Getting Pushed to GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict some files from ever being pushed to a git repo?

I have a file with username and password information that I want to make sure will never get pushed to my repo for obvious reasons.

I am using git for my version control. I was wondering if it is possible to have git not allow my file "passwords.txt" to be uploaded to my repo. So if I were to accidentally add, commit, and push the file it would throw an error saying something like "Cannot push passwords.txt to the repo."

Is this possible, or do I just need to be very carful when adding and committing my files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply too risky to try and never push the file.

Make sure your `password.txt` is not versioned (`git rm --cached`, and added to the `.gitignore`)

Then you can register a `smudge` script, which will *generate* the file with sensitive information on `git checkout`.

That is part of a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309), using using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

That '`smudge`' script( that you have to write) would need to:

- fetch the right values (from a source *outside* the repo, that way no risk to add and push by mistake)
- generate the  `password.txt`, using a tracked manifest *template*  `password.txt.tpl` with placeholder value in it to replace.

That means:

- the template `password.txt.tpl` is added to the git repo
- the generate file `password.txt` is declared in the `.gitignore` file and never versioned (and never pushed).

Answer (score 3):

In your project folder, create a `.gitignore` file.

Then in the file, insert this line:

```
passwords.txt
```

**The .gitignore file will tell Git what to ignore.**

**You can ignore files and folders.**

If you've accidentally committed the `passwords.txt` before, tell Git to exclude it from now on with this command:

```
git rm --cached passwords.txt
```

Running `git status` will show `passwords.txt` as an untracked file so it won't be included in future commits - so keep the .gitignore file updated.

To see usage patterns, you'd want to reference the [gitignore manual.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

See more use cases at [github octocat](https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657) and [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/)

Comment: however, if you don't realize, you accidentally added the ```passwords.txt``` it will still be pushed to the repository