# Can you apply the same commit on a different file in a working directory?

Tags: git, github, version-control

For example, let's say I have two files, A and B. I created B as a copy of A but I want them to be very similar - I only want a couple lines different in B. Is there a way in Git to sync these changes in any way, or a more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit. It is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps a quick example would clear things up.

Comment: I'd rather consider a different design, for it looks to me that you suffer from duplication of code. Unfortunately, there exists no tool that is able to help in dealing with a poor design.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking this was a design issue. But let's say I have a method in both files with most of the code the same. However, I make changes in one file that I want to change in the other file.

Comment: @rb612 this is a bit off-topic and I don't know what language you are using, but consider something like the template method pattern to deal with such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can *generate* that difference, then you could:

- version `A`
- don't version `B` at all (and add it to your `.gitignore` actually)
- add a smudge script which, when reading A content `git checkout` would *generate* `B`.

This is called a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309), using a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: filter]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You have the following options:

1. Use [apply-patch-to-file](https://github.com/mprpic/apply-patch-to-file). Where you can generate the patch using:

   ```
   git format-patch HEAD^
   ```

And then apply using:

```
apply-patch-to-file -i ~/patches/0001-my-test-commit.patch
```

You will be prompted and asked on what files the patch should be applied.

2. Use directly the `patch` command, by creating the diff like:

   ```
   git diff HEAD^ -- hello.test > ~/patch_file
   ```

Then apply the diff to a different file:

```
patch -p1 another_path/subdir/different_file.test ~/patch_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the diff changes in a file and patch A and B individually using this patch file.