# How save or safately avoid the key of Social Networks like Facebook or LinkedIn in GitHub

Tags: ios, facebook, git, github, linkedin-api

Some tutorials recommend don´t save a key in `GitHub` for **security** reasons, they to keep the file in `.gitignore` but for example some **Social Networks** like `Facebook` or `Linkedin` create a key in `Info.plist` file.

The `Info.plist` contains many others settings of the app and must be commit.

How can I keep in **safe** my key and commit the `Info.plist` normally.

Example of `Info.plist` (`CFBundleURLSchemes` and `FacebookAppID`)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb355414950742780</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>355414950742780</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too risky to try and never push the `Info.plist` file.
It is safer to *not* version it (`git rm --cached <File>`, and added to the `.gitignore`)

Then you can use a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309), using using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309):

Register a `smudge` script, which will *generate* the file with sensitive information on `git checkout`.

[image]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

That '`smudge`' script( that you have to write) would need to:

- fetch the key (from a source *outside* the repo, that way no risk to add and push by mistake)
- generate the  `Info.plist` file, using a tracked *template*  `Info.plist.tpl` with placeholder value in it to replace.

That means:

- the template `Info.plist.tpl` is added to the git repo
- the generate file `Info.plist` is declared in the `.gitignore` file and never versioned (and never pushed).