# Ignore local changes in the file and update it on pull

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-index

We have a repo with a file say `x.APK` that is pulled by client machines.
These client machine will modify this file and keep it locally for their use.

In normal usage we will update this file very rarely say once in 2-3 months.
The first time it will pull the files many along with `x.APK` and modify it and store it locally. We then update other files and push. On pull in client we get a local change but since `x.APK` did not change there are no conflicts.
Now is there any way to update `x.APK` ignoring whatever local changes were made to that file with only `git pull`.

`git pull` are done by a script and we cannot access the clients always. so running other commands will be tricky.

We tried:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

this ignores the changes but is not able to pull

Using `gitignore` it will delete the file from the clients and repo which we don't want.

It is a peculiar case if someone could help out it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the local modification done in x.txt.

If those modifications are well defined (and not all over the place in `x.txt`) then you could consider a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) in order to generate the right `x.txt` on checkout:

- it means that you do not version `x.txt` anymore, but a template version "`x.template`".
  `git mv x.txt x.txt.tpl`.
  Add `x.txt` to your `.gitignore`.
- Then, add a smudge script associated to `x.txt` files in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309):

  ```
  x.txt filter=updatex
  ```

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

```
git config filter.updatex.smudge 'update_x'
```

The `style_smudge` script can be versioned, and will have to fetch local modification content from a file outside the repo (meaning those a *private* modification), and inject its content in the template in order to generate the actual `x.txt`.

That way, a `git pull` which triggers an update of the working tree would automatically re-generate `x.txt` with the new updates as well as the local modifications.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been a more specific, it is not txt but rather a android APK

Comment: @goldsmit409 an apk file? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package). That is a binary (archive), no? If so, ... not much to do expect to *not* modify it locally (or to modify a copy, and reports the changes each time the apk changes)

Comment: yes apk is the binary android file, basically a container file for android apps. Seems like I cannot achieve what I want. Maybe the modified files has to move out the repo but it will be a long process and want to avoid it

Comment: @goldsmit409 isn't possible to use the content filter driver I mention to re-generate the right content for that apk on each checkout?

Comment: I am going to read about the filter you mention, its new to me but is it something (taking a wild guess) like diff is created from original to modified file and then that diff is applied. Also the modification I am looking to do is that pushing a APK ~15mb OTA is a huge network task which we dont have access to in remote. So we push diff ~1-2mb that are Ok for us and this is what modifies the file

Comment: @goldsmit409 actually, the filter can be any script you want. As long as you have a way to rebuild the right content for the apk file, you can then declare that process as a "content filer driver".

Comment: Why do you have a build artifact in the version control system in the first place? That's not an optimal solution.

Comment: It's not actually a build artifact, it is actually the final APK that is relased. As I said before we have a peculiar system. I know git is not supposed to be used as we are using but to update a lot of clients with latest code and APK's this was a solution for us.