# Do not overwrite config file on Azure using GIT

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, config

I have a web application that is hosted on Azure.
There are currently a few web sites that are using the same code which is retrieved from bitbucket.
The only difference between the various installations is that they have a different connection string in the `web.config` files that targets different databases.

Whenever I am making a bug fix I upload my new code on bitbucket and Azure gets this code from BitBucket.
There are currently 5 applications that get the same code and each time I upload new code on bitbucket I have to manually edit the `web.config` file on Azure in order to target the correct database for each app.

Is there a way to instruct Azure not to overwrite the `web.config` file when It receives new code from Bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

On possibility is to *not* version `web.config`, but a template file `web.config.tpl`, and a value file (with values for each applications)

Then, you can use a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The generated actual `web.config` remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).
That means your actual working tree does not get "dirty".

The smudge script selects the correct value file and *generates* the correct `web.config` based on the template the smudge script is applied on during a `git checkout`.

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility to change settings based on the website you are deploying could be in the release. [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/) supports releasing software from a source like BitBucket to Azure. 
Create a VSTS account. Create a project within the account.
Create a new build and configure BitBucket as source.
Create a release to deploy the webapplication to each of the five places.
Use the variables to set a different connectionstring for each webapplication.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't need to hardcode connection strings in `web.config` at all. Just pick it up in your code from Application Settings.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/:

> For .NET apps, these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name..

```cs
using System.Configuration;

// Define AzureSQLConnStr in Portal -> Web App -> Application Settings
string AzureSQLConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureSQLConnStr"];
```

Application Settings/Connection Strings defined in the Portal will override the values from `web.config` / `app.config` at runtime.