# push to separate branches for Firebase, stripe ect

Tags: git, firebase

I am a developer trying to work in to releasing my first IOS app (Swift 3). So far, I have been using firebase and stripe API's . As I release, I want to create 3 projects. One is a release, (Aka all the live data). The second is test. and the third is development.

My question is, is there a way I can work on a development branch, which is connected to a 'developement' firebase project, and then push to a test branch, which connects with a 'test' firebase project, and then a live branch, connected to a 'live firebase project'?

I know I can do all this by hand, but is there a way with software to just know what branch I am on, and then move all the api keys?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: Git can definitely handle this, just maintain separate branches for each release.  But if you're asking for a full explanation of how to do this, then your question is too broad.

Comment: Just read it, Big help. But If I have a configuration to work with each database, i.e. "APIKEYFORDEVELOPEMENT" and "APiKEYFORRELEASE" in my configuration, Is there a way I can have those change with the branches?

Answer (score 1):

> But If I have a configuration to work with each database, i.e. "APIKEYFORDEVELOPEMENT" and "APiKEYFORRELEASE" in my configuration, Is there a way I can have those change with the branches?

One possible solution is to *generate* the right configuration file depending on the branch you have checked out.
For that, version `config.dev` and `config.master`, but use only the right one to generate a final config file with the right values.
See [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792406/6309).