# Ignore files when merging branches

Tags: git, merge

When I merge branches I am trying to ignore `web.config` between each branch because each branch have different configuration in web.config.

Some reason, it is not working.
Am I missing something?

This is what i have so far.

#### .gitattributes

```
* text=auto
Web.config merge=ours
```

#### File Structure

```
 .gitignore
 .gitattributes
 project
 |____directory
 |____directory2
      |_____Web.config
```

I also set merge.ours.driver to true:

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> today I added a few new files and change some files but when i merge locally, this is not working.

A [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies) like `merge=ours` only applies on specific files when they *have conflicts*. If you change a file only in one branch, then merge that branch, there is no conflict (ie, no concurrent modification).

In other words, `merge=ours` is *not* the right solution for your case (whether or not you are using Visual Studio 2015).

I would rather:

- have a separate file per branch (`web.config.master`, `web.config.mybranch`, ...), in which you can modify each file as you want
- declare a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)** (using a [.gitattributes declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) which would, on checkout automatically copy the right file as `web.config`.
  That `web.config` copied file would remain ignored and private.

[image: smudge]

Your `smudge` script can determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: This is new for me, where do i add the smudge and what do i place in the smudge. Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @Valter See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309 (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2318063#2318063) the smudge script needs to be in your $PATH. But anyway, you did chose the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You almost there, you missed something small - to mark the **exact** file that you wish to ignore. you have it with **capital letters** or if its right and nested it should be with `**/web.config`

```
echo 'web.config merge=ours' >> .gitattributes
echo '**/web.config merge=ours' >> .gitattributes
```

Do it and it will work.

Comment: It worked fine yesterday, today i added a few new files and change some files but when i merge locally, this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Diff & Merge Tools Git Setting is set to Visual Studio. Do you think this is the issue.