# How to display code in certain format but commit in another?

Tags: javascript, git, intellij-idea, coding-style

Me and a friend of mine are working on a codebase and a problem has arisen. So, I gladly adhere to any common style standard which has some tooling support for auto-format. My friend has harder to read code and strongly prefers things like functions in the following format

```
function foo()
{
    console.log('bar');
}
```

This helps him to distinguish the beginning and end of blocks.

Compare to this format where the opening bracket is on the same line as the function keyword.

```
function foo() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

Is there any smooth way of enforcing a code style in the project while allowing a developer to view and seemingly add code in their preferred format? I've read about git hooks which I assume could be a part of formatting the code before commit. I cannot however find a full solution for the described scenario.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170216.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [.gitattributes declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: smudge]
[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/clean.png]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The idea is do apply a code format on checkout, and apply another one on checkin, automatically.

So for any `*.java` file, you would called a formatter able to display the function block with the right curly brace policy on checkout, or with the original policy on commit.