# GIT (HUSKY): exit code when a file is being committed?

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

is there a way to check if a file is being committed and exit with an error ?

I have a file in git that needs to be there but should never be modified and i was hoping to use husky as a pre-commit - so if anybody tries to modify the file and commit then it would throw an error.

If in future I need to modify the file then i can just disable the pre-commit.

the file is a configuration that i need to edit a lot when developing but the changes should never be committed.

I was hoping to use husky as a check to ensure that i dont.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather manage sure a file with a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

That means you do *not* version the actual configuration file, but only a **template** file, and a file with all possible values per environment.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The generated actual file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`): your actual working tree does not get "dirty".

The `smudge` script:

- detect the right environment (not the branch, since only one is needed)
- selects the correct value file and *generates* the correct file based on the template the `smudge` script is applied on during a `git checkout`.

That way, you modify the `config.dev` value file as much as you want when developing: the config file (not versioned) will be generated from those values.
But in production, a checkout of that same repo will trigger the generation of a prod config file, using the `config.prod` (versioned file) values.