# Git: How do I rebase Branch Feature back onto Branch Develop minus Branch MyLocalChanges

Tags: git, merge, rebase

We have a *develop* branch and many *feature* branches that are created from *develop* as needed and will eventually be merged back into *develop*.

When I work, I have a set of local changes I like to make, these are  changes to settings, changes to scripts, changes to modules, etc. that change various flags, or change log messages, or do this or that differently from how much of the team works.

I'd like to keep those changes in a branch based on *develop* called *MyLocalChanges* which would be developed and merged (?) into what *feature* branch I am working on, but which never be merged back into *develop*

And then in the end, when everything has been tested, I'd like to either create a pull request or do a rebase of (*Feature* - *MyLocalChanges*) onto *Develop* and I'd like to do that from the command line, without using `rebase -i`

Perhaps it might be expressed like this:

```
git merge (feature - (diff mylocalchanges develop)) develop
```

How do I do this in git? What is this sort of subtractive merge or rebase called?

Comment: Did you look at `git stash`? It may be more useful for your kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not trivial to merge a commit "minus some changes", it is best to:

- only version *template* files, filled with default values valid the team
- have private files with your own value
- version a script able to generate the actual config files, with the right values: those generated files would also be private (that way, no issue when merging)

See an example of such a [content filter driver here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141107/6309).