# dont merge Specific files in git

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git

**What I Want**
I working in windows and my project is asp.net mvc
I have two branches .Test and Master.
In both branches, i have config.cs
Each branch has its own config.cs with different data.
I want the config.cs files, Do not include in the merge.

**my directory**

> -.git
>   -.vs
>   -MyProject
>      --config.cs
>   -.gitattributes.txt

**my try**
I found this link:
[git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)
Who says to use the .gitattributes.txt

I write this line into .gitattributes.txt
`config.cs merge=ours`
and run this line:
`git config --global merge.ours.driver true`

But not work.
When I merge the Test branch into the Master branch, config.cs of Test, overrides on config.cs of Master.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to merge that file, it is better to not version it at all, but to *generate* it.

That generation would be through a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

Again:

- you don't version `config.cs` at all (actually, remove it with `git rm config.cs`, followed by a commit)
- version a **template** file `config.cs.tpl`, and two files with all possible values per environment (`Test` and `master`, so `config.cs.test` and `config.cs.master`).

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The generated actual file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`): your actual working tree does not get "dirty".

The `smudge` script:

- detect the right environment (like the branch, with `branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)`)
- selects the correct value file and *generates* the correct file based on the template the `smudge` script is applied on during a `git checkout`.

That way, you modify the `config.cs.test` value file as much as you want when developing: the `config.cs` file (not versioned) will be generated from those values.
But in `master`, a checkout of that same repo will trigger the generation of a master `config.cs` file, using the `config.cs.master` (versioned file) values.