# how to except files from be merged to other git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two branches: one for development and another for production,
each one has its own config values in app.config file

what I want is to ignore these values whenever I merge or rebase these branches.

Comment: Then perhaps you best bet would be to not even version the `app.config` file in the first place.  Is there any reason why it is currently being versioned?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , yes because it has other than these config values and I want them to be shared with other team members

Comment: Then maybe have one versioned file for common properties, and other config files which can be branch specific.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , OK thanks, I got this solution in mind but I was wondering if there is a better way to achive that

Comment: If your app.config file differs from the one that is versioned consider having a separate unversioned app.config for your local development (if I understand correctly that the versioned app.config is for production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then perhaps you best bet would be to not even version the app.config

Exactly, but you can still *generate* it, with a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

What you would version is a **template** file, and a file with all possible values per environment (per branch).

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The generated actual file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`): your actual working tree does not get "dirty".

The `smudge` script:

- detect the right branch
- selects the correct value file and *generates* the correct file based on the template the `smudge` script is applied on during a `git checkout`.

That way, you modify the `config.<branch>` value file as much as you want: the config file (not versioned) will be generated from those values.
And it won't have any merge issue.