# How to use a git filter to implement a local code style different from the repository style?

Tags: git, filter, coding-style, clang-format

A few elements of the coding style of the project annoys me. For example, I prefer 80 character line length, I never want the condition and the statement on the same line for an if (for breakpoint placement), etc.

I would like to use a git filter to transform the code from the upstream repo to my preferred format, use the preferred format during development and then transform it back when I push.

The project uses clang-format so there is a quite well defined style.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK!** As far as I am aware, the git filter was not designed for this purpose!

Having said that, this is possible with some caveats and I have a working setup  that I will share.

**Prerequisites**

The repo needs to use a style enforcing tool, like `clang-format`, that can be used as a pipe. The formats and the formatting tool needs to satisfy the following property: if you start with a repository style formatted file, and apply the local format and then the repository format, then you get the original file back.

**The way**

Assume that the repository style is based on the LLVM style with the maximum line length modified to 150 characters, while you prefer maximum 80 character long lines. You want to do the style transformation for only a single file `path/file.cc`. Start with a clean repository state.

Create `.git/info/attributes` with the following content:

`path/file.cc filter=style`

Put into the `.git/config` the following:

```
[filter "style"]
    clean = <path>/upstream-style.sh %f
    smudge = <path>/local-style.sh %f
```

The mentioned, `upstream-style.sh` script has:

```
#!/bin/bash

<path>/clang-format --verbose --style="{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, ColumnLimit: 150}"
```

while `local-style.sh` has:

```
#!/bin/bash

<path>/clang-format --verbose --style="{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, ColumnLimit: 80, 
                                        ReflowComments: false}"
```

The files are not reformatted yet, because there were no git operations. One simple way to trigger the reformatting is to switch to another branch and back.

**Caveats**

We rely on that executing `local-style.sh` and then `upstream-style.sh` (or the other way around) you get exactly the same file back. This is not at all guaranteed with all style options.

In particular, comments could be a problem. The option `ReflowComments: false` should help with comment blocks, but in-line comments will most likely remain an issue. A line with in-line comments that is longer than the allowed length, may be broken up and not returned to its original form during the transformations.

There should be no issue if comments and code are never on the same line. Inidentally, I prefer to follow that maxim. (I favor to use comment blocks at the beginning of files, classes, functions and not interspersed inside functions.)

The `git diff` command may not show the correct line numbers.

**Notes**

The scripts receive the file names that are being formatted. However, it would be a mistake to use the file name when invoking clang-format. You may get a 'file not found' error, because the disk may not have a copy at the time the script executes.

Having the name in the script can still be useful. I use it to print a message to standard error, for example:

`>&2 echo "Formatting $1 for local."`

If something goes wrong, comment out the lines in the `attributes` file and reset the repository.

I am using this solution successfully. I had no problem during commit, rebase, cherry-pick.