# How to force .clang-format on multiple github repos

Tags: git, clang-format, multiple-repositories

I'm using multiple C++ github repositories, they all share (as a company standard) the same .clang-format file.
We decided to put this file in a separate repository in order to be able to track changes. I'm looking for a way to publish modifications in this file to all relevant repositories.
Doing that manually is not and option because I have many repositories.

1. I thought to have this repository as a git submodule but in this solution I can't clone the submodule in the root of the repo.
2. Thought to clone it into a directory and have a symbolic link to the submodule, but can I have symbolic links in Windows ? the repos are shared between Windows and Linux and Mac
3. Have all the repos as a submodules of the clang-format repository and have a script which update all the submodules and create a pull-request automatically.
4. Same as 3 but without the submodules, clone each repo and copy the new file
   Do you have any other better option ?

Answer (score 1):

While submodule remains the best option (especially [with an associated branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), which makes updating its content as easy as `git submodule update --remote`), you would still need a preprocessing step before building.

I usually version a `build.bat` script (like [this one for instance](https://github.com/VonC/gitw/blob/master/build.bat)) in charge of setting up the environment and building the project.

That script can also check if the `.clang-format` is present at the root folder and, if not, copy it from the submodule.

Since every user of that repository will have to call `build.bat` to... build the project, they won't even have to be aware of that preprocessing step.

---

The [OP sagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3164467/sagi) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71372269/6309):

> but build phase might be a little late because I want the formatting to happen in the IDE while coding.

That is where a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) declared in a `.gitattributes`  file can help.

You still need to each user to type a command first:

```
git config --global filter.clang.smudge 'script_install_clang'
```

And you need to verion a dummy file `.clang-format.tpl` to associate that particular file with the `smudge` script.

But the idea that the smudge script will be called on `git clone` or `git checkout`/`git switch` automatically, and can set up any missing file for you.

That way, the format file is ready as soon as you are launching your IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I have a Makefile (or similar) on every source repo so I can use it for the update of the submodule and the sync of the file, but build phase might be a little late because I want the formatting to happen in the IDE while coding.

Comment: @sagi OK. I have edited my answer to address your requirement.